# What's the difference between these two enum [Flags] declarations (C#)

Tags: c#, enums, bit-manipulation, bit

This is more a question I'm asking to understand rather than figure out a problem. Consider the following two:

```
[Flags]
    public enum Flags
    {
        NONE = 0x0,
        PASSUPDATE = 0x1,
        PASSRENDER = 0x2,
        DELETE = 0x4,
        ACCEPTINPUT = 0x8,
        FADE_IN = 0x10,
        FADE_OUT = 0x20,
        FADE_OUT_COMPLETE = 0x40
    }

[Flags]
    public enum Flags
    {
        NONE = 0x0,
        PASSUPDATE,
        PASSRENDER,
        DELETE,
        ACCEPTINPUT,
        FADE_IN ,
        FADE_OUT,
        FADE_OUT_COMPLETE
    }
```

If I do bit checking on something using the latter enum there sometimes is overlap (I think something like `DELETE` is interpreted as `PASSUPDATE | PASSRENDER`, while in the first example each entry is independent of the other (i.e. `DELETE` is only `DELETE` and cannot be proven using a combination of a different set of flags).

Comment: Show the code where Delete is being evaluated as the two Pass?

Comment: The `[Flags]` attribute doesn't magically transform an enum into a binary enum.

Comment: You should re-think what this enum represents.  Clearly it started out representing a state, it doesn't make much sense to have fade-in, fade-out and fade-complete be active at the same time.  Be careful to avoid adding enum members that really should be a separate property.  Now remove [Flags], problem solved.

Comment: @Hans Passant I suppose you're right, might be better to break it off into two seperate enums. I stil will need [flags] since something can have PASSRENDER and PASSUPDATE set on them or just one.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Without explicit numbers, enums increment by 1 each time (even with `[Flags]` specified), so you get:

```
[Flags]
public enum Flags
{
    NONE = 0x0,
    PASSUPDATE, // = 1
    PASSRENDER,// = 2
    DELETE,// = 3
    ACCEPTINPUT,// = 4
    FADE_IN ,// = 5
    FADE_OUT,// = 6
    FADE_OUT_COMPLETE// = 7
}
```

which is simply not the numbers you wanted (and certainly isn't bitwise flags which are typically successive powers of 2)